# Why does C# say that the CCR's IterativeTask is non-generic?

Tags: c#, ccr

I'm using the [Concurrency and Coordination Runtime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_and_Coordination_Runtime) and am writing code similar to what is described in the documentation. The following line fails to compile:

```
yield return new IterativeTask<string,Object,Object,long[]>("Hi",a,b,ls, itfunc);
```

The compiler gives this error message:

```
The non-generic type 'Microsoft.Ccr.Core.IterativeTask' cannot be used with type arguments
```

Which is mistifying because the documentation uses that method with type arguments and it's clearly generic.

(I'm going to post my own answer here, that's [encouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/stackoverflow-should-i-answer-my-own-question-or-not) as I understand it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that there is a limit to the number of generic parameters one can use with IterativeTask: it can take three but no more.

So, this code compiles (once you change itfunc to use one fewer argument):

```
yield return new IterativeTask<string,Object,long[]>("Hi",a,ls, itfunc);
```

If you really do need all the information in the arguments, you can create some type to hold them:

```
struct Z {
  string msg;
  Object one;
  Object two;
  long[] ls;
}

Z z = new Z { msg="Hi", one=a, two=b, ls= longs };
yield return new IterativeTask<Z>(z, itfunc);
```